# Why does the IC not respond (INA200)

Tags: circuit-analysis, integrated-circuit, circuit-design, current-measurement

The questions I have:

- Is the makeshift IC I use in the simulation a fair representation of the INA200?
- I assembled the circuit as shown in the picture (except for the current source and the LED) and I'm trying to get a response to prove that what I put together works but so far I was not able to see any response at the output (CMPout pin 6)
- If things start working the way I intend them to do, how can I tune the system to trigger at different current levels?

I'm currently trying to make a circuit which detects a raise in current using a shunt and an [INA200.](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ina200.pdf)

[image]

Here is a picture of the circuit:

[image: Figure 2]

I was using a makeshift INA200 for the simulation.

After putting it all together I realised that the INA200 was not responding to any given input on pin 7/8.

The configuration I was using:

1. 8V (Vs)
2. connected to 3.
3. connceted to 2.
4. GND
5. open
6. to 1N4148
7. shunt high
8. shunt low

Instead of the LED I was using a wire resistor and I was manually increasing the voltage to see if at any point the INA200 would trip and output ~7.7V but I was unable to do so (or to see it?)

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please edit your question and add a schematic as a connection description is hard to follow. The schematic editor here is a breeze to use. The better the quality of your question, the better the quality of the answers you will attract. Again, a warm welcome to the site.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend not using the makeshift attempt, but instead going to the [development resources](https://www.ti.com/product/INA200/toolssoftware) page of the TI product page and acquiring the [INA200 PSpice Model](https://www.ti.com/lit/zip/sbom865). No need to emulate or approximate when a SPICE-compatible model is available. If you're in LTspice, pull it in with [this](https://www.analog.com/en/technical-articles/ltspice-simple-steps-to-import-third-party-models.html).